# Facebook login button save state after login?

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

Hello I am using [this example](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/controls/login-ui-control/) to login on Facebook using Facebook .net sdk.Eveything works now I have to save the login button state i.e change the button state i.e from log in to log out and also if already connected the display the FB user's name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I managed to show the user profile and display user's name using the controls in Facebook.Client. I am trying to see how can i save the session state and log out the user if he /she clicked on "logout button"?

Comment: means, you are not able to logout from facebook, when using SDK?

Comment: Hello , actually once the user logged in when i re open the app i see the log in button again, so the user must click again on "log in" button. I want to save the state i.e once the user logged in, he should not log in again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If saving the state means you want to save information like `access_token`, profile details etc. Suppose you want to store the `access_token` only, you can save it to isolated storage:

```
     private void OnSessionStateChanged(object sender, Facebook.Client.Controls.SessionStateChangedEventArgs e)
            {
               if (e.SessionState == Facebook.Client.Controls.FacebookSessionState.Opened)
                {
                 string fb_access_token = ((Facebook.Client.Controls.LoginButton)sender).CurrentSession.AccessToken;
                 IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                 settings["fb_token"] = fb_access_token ;
                 settings.Save();
                }
             }
```

And in your application you can add a logout button, on its click you can delete `access_token` from isolated storage.

```
private void onLogOutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
           settings.Remove("access_token");                  
           settings.Save();
         }
```

On application launch you can check if access_token exist, you can navigate to another page. If not you can redirect to login page.

```
  private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("fb_token"))
        {                
    // Use this access token in application for fetching other user informations
            Uri nUri = new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);       
        }
        else
        {
            Uri nUri = new Uri("/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Hello there thanks for your answer i will check it asap and let you know :)

Comment: Are you able to solve your query? Have you tried this answer. Hope it will help you :)